# basic_string::_S_construct NULL not valid error fix required

Tags: c++

I'm writing a code which includes accepting inputs from the C++ command line. The program does not execute, and a gdb run says "basic_string::_S_construct NULL not valid". Here is the code snippet:

Can anyone look into this and help me sort this out?

```
int main( int argc,char *argv[])
{

    std::string structure=argv[1];
    std::string sorshuf=argv[2];
    int size=atoi(argv[3]);
    int RunNum=atoi(argv[4]);
```

Comment: did you provide 4 or more arguments into the program when running it?

Comment: yes I did. I made sure of that. My reading says the error has something to do with assigning a null to std::string, although I don't know why that's happening

Comment: `std::string` complains that it took a NULL as an argument. That's your first clue. Then, you can investigate why it's NULL - print the values of `argv` elements and the arrays they're pointing to.

Comment: I can't get it to run . I've tried printing the argv elements and everything, but the program gets stuck to some kind of infinite loop and gdb says sigabrt.           Also, I am entering a non null strings through the command line. I don't know why it string treats them as null

Comment: @Orthanc just post a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) along with the input you are giving, instead of all this mucking about

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <iostream>
int main( int argc,char *argv[]) {
    std::string structure=argv[1];
}
```

If you enter and run that program with *no* arguments, you get:

```
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::logic_error'
    what():  basic_string::_S_construct null not valid
    Aborted (core dumped)
```

which is pretty much exactly what you describe.

If you *add* an argument when running, the problem goes away.

Therefore, it's because no arguments are being provided at run time.

The only way you'll get a `NULL` in `argv[]` is if you've gone beyond the end of the array, since the standard mandates that as one way of detecting the end (the other being `argc` of course).

So you need to rethink your contention that you've provided enough arguments to the executable (as mentioned in a comment) - I think you'll find you're incorrect.

I would *start* by putting the following code right at the start of main:

```
std::cerr << "argc = " << argc << '\n';
if ((argc > 0) && (argv[1] == NULL)) std::cerr << "Urk! 1\n";
if ((argc > 1) && (argv[2] == NULL)) std::cerr << "Urk! 2\n";
std::cerr << "Past Urks\n";
```

Comment: As an aside, such a benign result is not guaranteed.

Comment: so, this is what I'm doing in my commandline

./benchtree bst sorted 31 5;

Comment: @Orthanc, if that's your command line and your code is as stated and it's actually called benchtree, it should work fine. Try the null checks at the bottom of my answer and, if they don't complain, then your problem almost certainly lies elsewhere (perhaps in other code assigning pointers to a string).

Comment: tried adding your code at the beginning of the main. Still no execution.

Comment: @Orthanc, what do you mean by "no execution"? Are you seeing any output at all? I'd suggest trying my minimal sample at the top of the question to see what happens.

Comment: The checks should be `if ( argc > 1 )` and `if ( argc > 2 )`.  It's UB to read `argv[2]` when `argc < 2` etc.

Comment: @paxdiablo when I press enter, the command line goes into an infinite loop kind of a thing. a gdb run gives me a basic_string::_S_construct NULL not valid error and SIGABRT

Comment: @Matt, wasn't meant to be production-ready code, just debug. But I've changed it to fix that.

Comment: @Orthanc, again, try my minimal example, then try again with the code added from the bottom.

Comment: Okay. I just got a past Urk message.

Comment: what is the argc when you run it?

Comment: @Orthanc, that code is _fine_ provided you give it an argument. So either you're running different code is your compiler is busted. Was the _any_ output from the minimal code with Urk outputting statements?

Comment: ./benchtree bst shuffled 31 5
argc = 5
Past Urks

This is the exact statement of the output. The program is stuck like previously

Comment: @Orthanc, and the minimal-with-urk example also gave you the abort? And there's no _other_ code being run, is there? I.e., the main is only what I gave, with no code afterwards, and there are no static objects being instantiated?

Comment: yes . The code is stuck in a loop as before after printing the urks message

Comment: Then there's something wrong with your environment, such as the libraries in use, or the debugger, or any of a dozen other things. The code you've shown has _no_ issue by itself so, unfortunately, the question cannot be answered in its current form.